# Encoding message format onto a buffer to send via UDP sockets?

Tags: sockets, chat, distributed-system

As a part of our project we need to decide on how to send a structure using sockets in a datagram packet. In order to do so we are not suppose to use any serialization through any third party libraries. From what I have come up with is to encode the structure fields into a buffer.

eg.

```
struct message {
   int sequence_number;
   string datamessage;
}
```

Now to send this structure we would encode this to a buffer which would be something like this

> /s"sizeofmessage"/i"sequence_number"/data"datamessage"

Is there any better way of achieving this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serialize the data any way you want as long as the format contains enough information for the receiving end to reconstruct the `struct message`.

I don't find your proposed format very clear:

```
/s"sizeofmessage"/i"sequence_number"/data"datamessage"
```

I don't know if you mean for those quotation marks to be literally present in the message and I don't know if you mean that the size of the message and the sequence number should be encoded as decimal strings in ASCII or as something else.

You should decide whether your protocol needs to be extensible in a way that allows the receiver to recognize a newer message format in case more fields to be added in the future. You need to decide if you will hard code something that deals only with the very simple structure you've presented above, or if you want something more flexible that might deal with a different structure. Keep in mind that the more extensible and flexible you make your serialization format, the more you may be tempted to change your decision not to use a ready-made serialization library.

But let's say you want to keep it very simple and design something that only handles this particular structure.

Here's something very simple that will work in your case:

- Send the sequence number. For example:

  - As a 4-byte integer in network byte order (big endian).
  - As a decimal number with digits send in ASCII, terminated with a non-digit character of your choice, such as `' '` (space)
  - (or anything else that is unambiguously decodable)
- Send the string as a sequence of bytes.

Because you are using UDP (datagram sockets), you need not send the length of the string or terminated it with any kind of special character. The receiver will know that all of the remaining bytes in the packet after the sequence number is decoded constitute the string.

This works as long as your messages will each fit in a single UDP packet (i.e. they are no bigger than about 64KB).

Comment: Thank You ! that is extremely helpful. I understood what you were trying to indicate, our protocol has two types of messages data messages and control messages. Based on what I have understood should I send the sequence number of the message to be sent separately from the string which is a part of the message ? 

What if the datagram holding the sequence number does not get delivered or is delayed so that the string gets delivered before that. I am confused thinking of this.

Comment: No, I meant to suggest that the sequence number and the string should be sent concatenated together in the same UDP datagram. Sorry for implying otherwise. Now, if you have 2 different types of messages, then either (1) each message should start with a discriminator that allows the receiver to tell them apart, which could just be a single byte at the start of the message that indicates the type, or (2) the data and control messages should be sent to different UDP ports.